# How to trace what cause "IndexError: list index out of range" and how to find prod(column)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the list and I have already convert it to 20 x 20 list.. ?

```
import numpy as np

a = \
'08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 '\
'49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 '\
'81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 '\
'52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 '\
'22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 '\
'24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50 '\
'32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70 '\
'67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 '\
'24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 '\
'21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 '\
'78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 '\
'16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 '\
'86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58 '\
'19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40 '\
'04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66 '\
'88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 '\
'04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 '\
'20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 '\
'20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 '\
'01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'
```

Here how I convert the list to 20x20 matrix;

```
# rearrange a
a = a.split(' ')

# map a.str to a.int
a = [int(x) for x in a]

# create b = 20x20 matrix
b = [[ 0 for x in range(20)]for y in range(20)]

# assign b[i][j] = a[i] and set k = i for a[i]
k = 0
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
        b[i][j] = a[k]
        k += 1
```

I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/SEMUA/Euler/Euler11.py", line 55, in <module>
    if np.product(b[i:i+4][j]) > largest:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

which refer to this part;

```
#column
for j in range(0,20):
    for i in range(0, 17):
        if np.product(b[i:i+4][j]) > largest:
            largest = np.product(b[i:i+4][j])
```

Why there is no same error here even though I use the same numbering;

```
#row
for i in range(0,20):
    for j in range(0,17):
        if np.product(b[i][j:j+4]) > largest:
            largest = np.product(b[i][j:j+4])
```

I notice that it work if it is a row but not if it is a column.
How can I fix this?
How can I extract a column from my 2-D list?

Answer (score 0):

First, your initialization of the array could be done much easier:

```
aa = np.array(list(map(int, a.split())), dtype = np.int)
aa.shape = [20, 20]
```

You used `][`, which means that first you create a view of 4 rows, then you try to select the 19th row from this -- obviously not possible. Use `,`, then your indices will refer to different axes. I don't know what do you want to do, but if you want to find the consecutive 4 elements with the highest product in your array, this gonna do for you:

```
largest = 0
for i in range(0, 20):
    for j in range(0, 17):
        if np.product(aa[i, j:j+4]) > largest:
            largest = np.product(aa[i, j:j+4])
```

Same for columns:

```
largest = 0
for i in range(0, 20):
    for j in range(0, 17):
        if np.product(aa[j:j+4, i]) > largest:
            largest = np.product(aa[j:j+4, i])
```